# ERROR: Invalid input <n=n+0> appears for too big holes on SRTM when filling nulls in grass (r.fillnulls)

Tags: grass-gis

[Related to this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/460412/112339)

In the link above I described a case, when there is no null cells in raster, but there  are some empty tiles that are also treated of course as nulls. This time, I have checked it out, so I have a clean SRTM raster, all tiles are in their places. But SRTM has a particularity, that in mountaigneous regions it has nodata above certain heights. Thus, some holes there are 100 per 300 cells areas.
r.fillnulls with RST method goes:

```
Using RST interpolation...
Locating and isolating NULL areas...
100%
Growing NULL areas
Assigning IDs to NULL areas
 100%
Processing 17149 map holes
Filling hole 1 of 17149
ERROR: Invalid input <n=n+0>
```

So we have again this error, but this time because of too big holes.
I can either use other r.fillnulls parameters, but I am not sure edge parameter is exactly the thing I need here, or I can create a plato raster with maximum height value and use r.mapcalc to simply swap nodata with this values, all the same heights are too big at these holes and there vould be no effect on river network creation if I make some really high picks there.. :)

What is the best way to your opinion?
[image: This area is 100 per 300 cells]

Comment: Is using pre-filled tiles an option?

Comment: No, Brad, as these holes are on a single tile too, it won't help

Comment: I was suggesting using tiles from a different source, e.g. USGS has void-filled tiles.

Comment: Ah, I got it. Thanks. I haven't seen these prefilled tiles

Comment: I'll try it. But for the problem it's still interesting, what's the most appropriate method. Let, we don't have prefilled data...

Comment: I have found only 3-arc sec prefilled DEM. Is there 1-arc sec prefilled?

Comment: See https://www.usgs.gov/centers/eros/science/usgs-eros-archive-digital-elevation-shuttle-radar-topography-mission-srtm-1?qt-science_center_objects=0#qt-science_center_objects